Golang middleware not working for cleaning trailing white spaces
I am creating a simple middleware to clear any trailing slashes when a request URL hits my backend endpoint. However, this middleware was not triggered when a request URL with an additional slash is called. Does anyone know why? I have tried for a long time and can't get a solution. I would like to use it as a middleware and I don't wish to use StrictSlash(true) because it causes a redirect.
Expected Behaviour

"/health/" to become "/health"

Actual Result

Got Not Found error

func main() {
    // Create a new Gorilla Mux router (github.com/gorilla/mux)
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.Use(clearTrailing)

    router.HandleFunc("/health", healthHandler)

    log.Println("Serving on port 7000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":7000", router)
}

// clearTrailing removes trailing slashes from the URL path
func clearTrailing(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Path = strings.TrimRight(r.URL.Path, "/")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

// Handler for /health endpoint
func healthHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("OK"))
}



You have not configured any action for route /health/, for the middleware to even act on  it

@Inian I have "/health", when a request comes as "/health/", I want to middleware to trim the additional trailing "/" at the end so it correctly hits "/health"

What I meant was, for this to even work, you need to duplicate the route for both /health/ and /health, so that when the request hits the former, it gets routed to the latter. As per the code you have, you don't even specify the route for /health/. How do you expect the middleware to act on it?

You could remove router.Use(clearTrailing) and instead do:
http.ListenAndServe(":7000", clearTrailing(router))


I believe what prevents you from trimming in the middleware is that router matches the path first, then adds the middlewares to the handler here:
https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/main/mux.go#L152
 func (r *Router) Match(req *http.Request, match *RouteMatch) bool {
    for _, route := range r.routes {
        if route.Match(req, match) {
            // Build middleware chain if no error was found
            if match.MatchErr == nil {
                for i := len(r.middlewares) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
                    match.Handler = r.middlewares[i].Middleware(match.Handler)
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    ...

I think StrictSlash is the better option here or what @mkopriva suggested.
Can I ask why you don't want to use it?
